# OpenAM auth chain that allows login for Administrative users only?

Tags: openam

#### Scenario:

I have an `OpenAM` instance with only the default realm configured. I have set up my Organization Auth Chain with a single `LDAP` module that allows my users to self register.

I also have set up another chain, called `adminChain` and set as the Administrator Auth Chain, with a single `Data Store` module in order to allow the `amAdmin` user to login using the `/console` url.

#### Problem:

My problem is that this second chain allows also non-admin users from the `LDAP` data store to login, which actually makes sense because it's using the `DataStore` module. But then how can I prevent normal users logging in with the admin chain? I want them to be limited to a specific chain only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the root realm for administration and sub-realm for operations.

In fact OpenAM will use all configured user data stores in a realm when it's configured to support the requested operation.

As a workaround you could set the value of `Authentication Naming Attribute` in the user data store config to an attribute which does not exist in the entries. This will make 'datastore' authentication for regular users fail. AmAdmin can still authenticate because this identity is stored in a special data store which does not show up in OpenAM configuration.

Be aware that you may be subject of a bug, as in older versions the DN-Cache is leveraged during authentication.

Comment: I will try to setup a subrealm in my test env and see if I can achieve all of the requirements this way. As a temporary workaround I added a Server Side Scripted Module to the admin chain that checks if the username is "amAdmin" - not pretty, but seems to work. 
I have also disabled the DN-cache at the moment as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works well, plus it is more logical and fits all of my requirements much better, thank you!